# How does one reduce the apparent effect of gravity without falling?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

There are things like the [Vomit Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vomit_Comet) to simulate zero-gravity for small periods, but that involves going into a steep dive in an airplane.  How could one get the same effect on a surface of the Earth?

("You can't" is an acceptable answer.)

Comment: You basically answered your own question: vacuum and slow motion. Having said that, the discussion of paranoia belongs into psychology.stackeschange.com and not the physics section.

Comment: This is a comprehensive debunking the "Moon Landing Hoax" claim from a really interesting perspective. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGXTF6bs1IU

Comment: @CuriousOne This isn't about how to fake it, it's about how to actually do it.  Or if falling is the only way.  I'm going to remove the Moon hoax part, it's distracting.

Comment: In that case "one can't" is the proper answer. Gravitation is equivalent to acceleration. The only way to escape it is to be in free fall, which we are doing on the ISS.

Comment: I stumbled on an answer in a citation in [What If](http://what-if.xkcd.com/124/).  This paper on [Humans Running in Place on Water at Simulated
Reduced Gravity](http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchObject.action?uri=info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0037300&representation=PDF) mentions a reduced gravity simulator. It turns out to be just suspending people from a cord, but such a device exists to attempt to reduce the effect of gravity for scientific purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Going under water would have a similar effect, thats how astronauts train for performing operations in 0 gravity like space walks ect i believe.